# Read Integers from Blob MySql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, blob

I am working with a open source application. I have a table like:

```
`id` mediumint(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`dbquery` text,
`nbrecs` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
`reclist` longblob,
```

In the reclist are stored ids of records that are linked to the present id. Example:

I have a collection with id 2 and Name Poetry. In rectlist, are all ids of books that are poetry. I have no ideea why the developers had to use blobs instead of another table, like it would be normal in MySql. I tryed to use select query, still blob returned. I tried:

```
SELECT CONVERT(reclist USING utf8) FROM table_name WHERE id=some_id;
```

And it return x into phpmyadmin SQL window. How can I see records from this blob? I am using Python, but really any example will help.

Comment: Can you give an example of the data in the blob column? If it is a string list of IDs, you'll somehow need to split it by comma, but MySQL doesn't have a split function.

Comment: I believe it should be array. Seeing them like a string or like a list, does not matter. It would be great to see them and use them.

Comment: But by "use them" you mean "use them as the value in a WHERE clause", which means the string "1, 2, 3" is very different from the array [1, 2, 3].

Comment: Yes, i know. But i will use them in a python script, so they can be converted/splitted, etc